# Reading error in Cassandra one some queries

Tags: cassandra

My table movies has a column containing a list with genres of that movie.

I tried to put an INDEX on the data.

```
CREATE INDEX ON movies (genres);
```

When I try do list all movies of the genre Documentary or Musical, I am getting results.

```
Select * from movies where genres contains 'Documentary';
```

But trying to list all movies of other genres like Thriller, Comedy or Crime, I am getting an Error:

```
Select * from movies where genres contains 'Thriller';

ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to list your psuedo-column name before the ON statement.

```
CREATE INDEX new_genres ON movies (genres);
```

If you are just trying to view a certain genre you could:

```
SELECT genres 
FROM movies
WHERE genres LIKE 'DOCUMENTARY' 
and genres LIKE 'MUSICAL';
```

This will list specified genres corresponding to all the movies that they belong to.

I hope this helps?

Comment: i dropped the index and redid it, but it didn't change anything. And I somehow can't use LIKE...

Comment: I guess the first step and debugging this would be checking your connection with the server. Maybe try a very vague SELECT * FROM statement that you know works to test your program.

Answer (score 0):

You may face this error if `tombstone_failure_threshold` is exceeded.

You can try increasing the `tombstone_failure_threshold` in  cassandra.yaml or
clean up your tombstones by running nodetool repair and compaction.